# IPad and IPhone - backing up "corrupted" file - spyware on IPad

Tags: itunes, ipad, backup, malware

My IPad Backup failed because the back up is corrupt.
Deleting the back up using iTunes or Windows File Explorer and repeating did not work. During Backup to my PC I got multiple popups from ESET NOD32 stating I had "adware" spyware on my IPad. NOD32 erased them on my PC but not IPad. Repeating the back up failed again.
I temporarily disabled NOD32 and the back up worked. But my IPad still has spyware on it.

Searching for spyware removal software or applications .. uncovered nothing. 
How do I remove spyware, adware, malware from my IPad??

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of Catch 22, but with a get-out clause...

If you let the Windows antivirus delete the suspect file, it will corrupt the backup.
However, as it is being recognised as a Windows virus by a Windows antivirus, then it almost certainly *cannot* actually have any effect on the iPad.

The iPad, of course, does not run Windows & cannot be infected by a Windows virus - even if it can 'carry' one & unfortunately, possibly pass it on.

One 'fix' would be to ensure your iTunes backups are encrypted [an option available in the Summary page in iTunes when your iPad is connected]  - that way the Windows antivirus can't even see the 'infection', nor, as the file would be encrypted & unreadable by Windows itself, could it infect your PC.

The other - more long-term - fix would be to delete the offending files from your iPad; your next backup would then be clean.